# adding functionality to a built in function (make Logger.error() do something else)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have imported `Logger` class and I have many calls to `Logger.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)` or `Logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)` in my code.

I want to make those functions (each of the `Logger.error/info/warning...`) do something else (such as call another function), without changing the calls themeselvs (hundreds of calls).

I that class was something I maintain, I would do something like this:

Change this

```
class Logger:
    def write(...):
```

into this:

```
class Logger:
    def write(...):
        #rename original write to _write and call it from here
        self._write()
        # call new function
```

and in this way, each call to Logger.write() would keep its old API, but will have an added functionality I desire.

How can I do something like this with a class I can't control?

Comment: You can use logging librarly. https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: Do you realise that you can just change members of classes? The `logging` module is pure Python, there are no true, immutable `builtin` types like `object`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Do you mean I can edit the `logging` class?

Comment: You can inherit from it, as in `class MyLogger(logging.Logger):`, or change it, as in `logging.Logger.write = my_log_method`. The later will affect the entire application, so beware.